# In angular material 15, error creating MatTabNav with tabPanel in separate component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a parent component that looks like:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-navigation></app-navigation>

<div class="app-container">
  <mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-tab-nav-panel>
</div>
```

The `app-navigation` components has:

```
  <nav mat-tab-nav-bar [tabPanel]="tabPanel">
    <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="[link.path]" routerLinkActive="mat-tab-label-active" class="subnav-link">
      ...
    </a>
  </nav>
```

`mat-tab-nav-bar` requires the `[tabPanel]="tabPanel"` and `#tabPanel` to target the correct route. However, when I do the above I get the error:

`Property 'tabPanel' does not exist on type 'NavigationComponent'`

This happens when the `[tabPanel]="tabPanel"` is not in the same component level as the `#tabPanel` However, I need them on different components.

Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Putting a '#variable' in a element makes it available just to its host component html scope (with some caveats as structural directives like *ngIf and *ngFor).

You need to pass that reference to the 'app-navigation' component, the most simple way is to add an @Input to the NavigationComponent class.

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTabNavPanel } from '@angular/material/tabs';

@Component({
// ...
})
export class NavigationComponent {
  @Input() tabPanel!: MatTabNavPanel;
}
```

You could make the input required, so the language-server and compiler can warn you about.

```js
@Input({ required: true }) tabPanel!: MatTabNavPanel;
```

Then, you have to pass the reference via input.

```html
<!-- Parent Component -->

<app-header></app-header>
<app-navigation [tabPanel]="tabPanel"></app-navigation>

<div class="app-container">
  <mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-tab-nav-panel>
</div>
```

For more information about input see https://angular.io/api/core/Input.
You also may need to check some angular tutorials on youtube.

Finally, I am not a native english speaker, sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: I tried this exact solution but I get javascript errors on load like "Cannot create property '_activeTabId' on string 'tabPanelViews'"